# Windows Form Paging like WebPage

Tags: c#, winforms

How to do paging in windows form project by showing the total pages? All I search and found is using buttons (previous, next, First, last). What I want is something like the paging in Forum (but it is web).

Example, if I have total 100 rows and 10/page, so I will have 10 pages. The GUI should show (1,2,3,4,5,6....10), which the number is clickable. It doesn't necessary is the link, may can a button as well. Winforms able to do this?

Exist a component to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, I always do I implement object using the BindingNavigator.

[image]

It is generally used to scroll through the records in a DataGrid.
Of course, managing the data source and with a bit of code is perfectly suited to paging in the WinForm. 
Specific components do not know, and also on DevExpress suggest to do so.

I hope I was clear and to the right idea.

Comment: Hi @daniele3004, it is something like a button or link to navigate to other page. e.g (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/images/paginierung/nnmru.gif) but in winforms

Comment: Hi @king jia. What do you mean 'other page'? 
At the time of navigation you want to reload the contents of a UserControl / Panel containing data?

Comment: The GUI shows number of pages, e.g (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11......90), if I click 11, it will navigate to page 11.

Comment: Ok....you can create dinamically button or button links ma would be very inefficient. In my image you can write the number of page and navigate without using the buttons. What you say I do it as I wrote in response.

Comment: However, I advise you to make it all work with a BindingNavigator for pagination in WinFor. Alternatively, you can create everything you need to code

Comment: sound's better!! Do you have any example code for that?

Comment: @king jia Later I'll write a simple example for you

Comment: @king jia Before preparing another answer I hope that my time was useful for you;-)

Comment: @king jia Thanks, I'm happy to check out was useful